# Asp.Net MVC 2 Html.TextBoxFor Best way to specify a format string for a DateTime property of model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, formatting, asp.net-mvc-2, html-helper

As the question title explains, what is the best way to specify a format which my Views use when displaying values of a `DateTime` property via the `Html.TextboxFor` method.

The default display includes the Date and Time where I really only want the Date displayed.

Thanks

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In your model definition add the [DisplayFormatAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute.aspx) to the DateTime property:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}")]
public DateTime Date { get; set; }
```

Then in your View call:

```
<%=Html.EditorFor(m => m.Date)%>
```

If all goes well you should get a TextBox with the value filled in in the format specified in the attribute definition.

Comment: I was missing a trailing curly brace in the DataFormatString. Make sure to include it.

Comment: One caveat: you can't specify custom HTML attributes (e.g. CSS class) with EditorFor.