# ASP.NET MVC 3: DisplayFormat Data Annotation for TimeSpan causing FormatException

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, data-annotations

In my model, the field Length is a TimeSpan with the following Data Annotation:

`[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{h\\:mm}")]`

which I used per the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869918/asp-net-mvc-2-html-textboxfor-best-way-to-specify-a-format-string-for-a-datetime).  I want the resulting textbox to display the current value for Length in hours and minutes.

However, in MVC 3 this doesn't seem to work anymore, because it causes a `FormatException`.  This exception occurs whether or not Length has an existing value.

Visual Studio adds, "When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object."  I don't even know what that means.  My variable is a TimeSpan, not a string, so why is it attempting to do a string conversion in the first place?  The dialog box reporting the exception gives a dead link.

This is the code in my view:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Length)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Length)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Length)
    </div>
```

The exception occurs at `Html.EditorFor()`.  I'm not sure what I'm missing here, does anyone have any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format specifier needs the position identifier:

```
{0:h\\:mm}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you!  I had dismissed that `0:` as something that would display the number of days.  Is that a carryover from C#'s WriteLine formatting?

Comment: Not exactly.  WriteLine uses string.Format(), as does DisplayFormatAttribute.  In fact, nearly all formatting in .NET ultimately uses string.Format at some point or another.